# How to print selected elements from file?

Tags: python, file

I wrote a code which print numbers from file like that:

```
data=open("fk.txt",'r')
for i in data:
    print i
```

And I got this:

```
fk id

5 4

4 4

1 2

11 13

10 17

18 17

5 8
```

I would like change this code,that it print only this elements which are higher than for exemple 6.I don't know how to split this in two list by columns.

Comment: What is `dane`? Please post your attempt at solving this - Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
with open("fk.txt") as file:   # Use file to refer to the file object
    data = file.readlines()
column1, column2 = [], []
for line in data:
    try:
        entry1, entry2 = line.split(' ')
        column1.append(int(entry1))
        column2.append(int(entry2))
    except ValueError:
        pass
print column1, column2
```

Comment: You don't need readlines, you are creating a list for no reason,  if there is more than one space between the digits your code won't work and you should not just pass when catching an exception, if there are only supposed to be numbers after the header you should not be ignoring any other error,

Comment: How does this select lines that are higher than for example 6, as requested?

Answer (score 4):

```
with open("fk.txt") as f:
    next(f) # skip header
    for line in f:
        if line.strip(): # catch empty lines
            a, b = map(int,line.split()) # cast to int
            if a > 6:
                print(a)
            if b > 6:
                print(b)
```

You accepted answer does not check if the number is greater or not so if you want two full columns of numbers regardless of value you can use zip to transpose the sublists:

```
with open("fk.txt") as f:
    next(f) # skip header
    col1, col2 = zip(*(map(int,line.split()) for line in f if line.strip()))
    print(col1,col2)
(5, 4, 1, 11, 10, 18, 5) (4, 4, 2, 13, 17, 17, 8)
```

Normally you should use a try/except but if there should only be numbers after the header then an error would be more appropriate